# Extjs float value is being passed as null in c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, floating-point

I have a float value in extjs model. For some reason any value I enter and pass to c# controller, its value is always null. I checked the json data being pass and I can see the passed value.

This is my extjs model

```
fields: [
    { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'FloatValue', type: 'float' },
    { name: 'RecId', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Valid', type: 'bool' }
 ]
```

C#

```
public class EmployeeRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public double? FloatValue { get; set; }
    public int RecId { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

JsonObject passed to controller

```
{ Id: 0, FloatValue: 0.1, RecId: 12, Valid: true }
```

On C# debug the value of 'FloatValue' is always null.

Is there something here that I am missing.

UPDATE -

```
var employee = new Object();
employee.Id = 0;
employee.FloatValue = 0.1;
employee.RecId = 12;
employee.Valid = true;

Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'POST',
        scope: this,
        url: 'EmployeeController/UpdateRecord',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonData: { employeeRec: employee },
        success: function (Response) {},
        failure: function () {}
});
```

C#

```
public static EmployeeRecord UpdateRecord(IList<EmployeeRecord> employeeRec)
    {
        //Here employeeRec.FloatValue is null but other property has their values.
    }
```

Comment: You can probably eliminate extjs from the equation. This is almost certainly a problem with your backend code. If you look in the network tab of your browser and see that the payload is being sent correctly, focus on the C#

Comment: Thanks Matt. I checked on the request payload and see the data. On c# all other data are there except the FloatValue. Do I have to define the float value in some way for it to be mapped correctly?

Comment: I haven't used ASP.NET MVC in a long time, so I'm not the best to help. However, you'll get more help if you show more of your code. How is `EmployeeRecord` getting used? What does the controller look like?

Comment: Sure Matt, any help will do. Please see my update. I have included what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Such behavior can appear brom an error in the getter or setter. You can give the correct valur to setter, but if it sets it badly, or getter afterwards gets something else than was written, you can easily see that null.

The most probably getter or setter simply won't do its work.